# I can't build or run my project

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to build and run my program. but I saw this message. what can I do?

> Rishe is app name

**Error 1 :**

[image]

**Error 2 :**
[image]

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

`android.name` is the class of your activity, not the application's name. Check the android developer's startup document.

Answer (score 0):

error1 -> there is conflict coming with your app module manifest file with other module manifest file. see manifest merger tool http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger or find how to merge mainifest file

error2 -> you are defining 3 activity with same name that is why it is giving error

Comment: validates resource references inside android XML files

Comment: are your sure your .rishe file comes under the package which define in manifestfile package="package name"  like this(packagename.rishe)